# Send user to external site in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to redirect a user to a different URL in coldfusion after the user logs out. Nothing comes to the top of my head besides linkTo() or urlFor() to accomplish this, but the thing is, I am not linking to another cfm page, I am wanting to send the user to a different URL completely.

What is the best way to send a user to a new URL after they signout, check code below.

```
public string function logOut() {
    auth.logOut();
    return forward('public.Home', 'home');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<cflocation>` tag comes to mind.  Inside a cfscript block, it's the `location()` function.  Details are in [the documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Location).

Comment: I have tried that and that works, but what I really need is a redirection after the user has logged out in my controller, there has to be something in Coldfusion to direct to a url outside of it's environment.

Comment: Change the signature of your function from string to void.  Replace the return command to a location function.  You can put whatever url you want as an argument in your location function.

Comment: Thank you! I am a .NET developer and just started CF at my job (learning curve for sure). Thanks again.